# Select query with covered Index resorting to index scan

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 31 columns in it and about 10 million rows

Given the following query

```
Select top (1000)
[CallType],
[AttributedCallType],
[Extension],
[CallDurationBacking],
[AnswerTimeBacking],
[AccountCode],
[AuthorisationCode],
[RequestedRoute],
[SelectedRoute],
[SelectedTrunk],
[ConditionCode],
[CalibratedTime],
[StoredDialledNumber],
[AttributedSiteNumber],
[AttributedExtension],
[Cost],
[AttributedCountry],
[PlanName],
[ClassificationName]
from CallRecords 
where ClientId = 15 and 
      Reported = 0 and 
      ResultCodeId > 1 
order by id
```

And the following covering index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_CallRecords_5_565577053__K2_K37_K31_1_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18_19_25_26_28_32_33_34_35_36_38_39] ON [dbo].[CallRecords]
(
    [ClientId] ASC,
    [Reported] ASC,
    [ResultCodeId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [CallType],
    [AttributedCallType],
    [Extension],
    [CallDurationBacking],
    [AnswerTimeBacking],
    [AccountCode],
    [AuthorisationCode],
    [RequestedRoute],
    [SelectedRoute],
    [SelectedTrunk],
    [ConditionCode],
    [CalibratedTime],
    [StoredDialledNumber],
    [AttributedSiteNumber],
    [AttributedExtension],
    [Cost],
    [AttributedCountry],
    [PlanName],
    [ClassificationName]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Why would the execution plan be using a clustered index scan?

I would have thought SQL server would have chosen a seek

How could i force if to use an index seek / key lookup?

[image]

Comment: You missed "[AttributedCallType]" column in INCLUDE column list?

Comment: Added that to the index and it still scanning

Comment: Make sure that your index is enabled and trusted: Query: SELECT * FROM   sys.check_constraints;

Comment: @sdrzymala nothing returns in sys.check_constraints

Comment: Don't assume the plan is wrong. If the criteria aren't very selective or the table statistics are out of date, the query optimizer will resort to a scan. Try executing the query with an INDEX hint and compare the execution plan of both queries. How many rows does this query return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get such result because of `Ordering by ID`.
Try deleting `order by id`. Among other things, you get non-relational results when ordering. Entrust ordering to your client application.

You can force select to use index using HINTS like:

```
from CallRecords WITH (INDEX(_dta_index_CallRecords_5_565577053__K2_K37_K31_1_3_4_5.....))
```

Comment: The ordering definitely was causing a problem